# Selenium IDE testing on maps(Open Layers)

Tags: selenium, openlayers, selenium-ide

I am working on testing an application with open layers maps using Selenium IDE. I researched a lot about clicking on the specific point on the map but I couldn't do it. Can you please provide me some start on this.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Rakesh

Comment: Can you give a little more information, what points do you want to click on? What have you tried so far? Did you try it maybe like this:

map.events.register('click', this, myhandler),
selenium.clickAt("map", "100,100")

Comment: Martin Thanks for the reply. The following are the commands I tried.
selenium.mouseMoveAt("id=OpenLayers.Control.MousePosition_4", "-111.06489,31.35118");
selenium.mouseDownAt("id=OpenLayers.Control.MousePosition_4", "-111.06489,31.35118");                                                            The search results return with some specific points. So when we click on those points , we will get the info regarding that place i.e. it gives popup

Comment: I do not know Selenium very well, but this is the clickAt function: clickAt(locator, coordString), where coordString "specifies the x,y position (i.e. - 10,20) of the mouse event relative to the element returned by the locator". I do not think that you can pass "real" coordinates there, you have to use screen coordinates.

Comment: You are right. Thanks for the info. Can I know how to convert the real coordinates to screen coordinates? It will be a great help for me.

Comment: Maybe this list letter, describing problems with Selenium and clicking in OL, helps: http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/openlayers-users/2012-November/026812.html

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want to change the open layers code from Selenium IDE you can run your own javaScript functions by using "runScript" as a command and write your javaScript code into the target field (don't use comments as everything is written in one line).

use the following script to fire a mousedown, mouseup and if you need a click event on the map:

```
var mousedownEvent = document.createEvent('MouseEvents'); 

mousedownEvent.initMouseEvent('mousedown', true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, yourX, yourY, false, false, false, false, 0, null); 

// creates an element from where the clickEvent can be fired
// instead of using pixel you can also refer to your dom-Element by id
document.elementFromPoint(16,118).dispatchEvent(mousedownEvent);

var mouseupEvent = document.createEvent('MouseEvents'); 

mouseupEvent.initMouseEvent('mouseup', true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, yourX, yourY, false, false, false, false, 0, null); 

// same element
document.elementFromPoint(16,118).dispatchEvent(mouseupEvent);

// in some cases a click event needs to be fired as well
```

Comment: Hi. I have tried your suggestion, but it does't work. I suppose I used it in the wrong way. Could you please explain it better and maybe show an example in a jsFiddle? Thanks