# How to test OpenLayers app with Selenium?

Tags: selenium, openlayers

I know this is and oldie, and I apologize for that. But I still haven't found a solution to this.

I have recently tried to test my OpenLayers-based app with Selenium. But when I click on the map, it doesn't detect the click in Selenium. I have searched all over the Internet. Some people say it is a bug from Selenium, other claim to have found a workaround.

I have tried all these solutions and I am getting no results. The clicks still don't work.

http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/Testing-with-selenium-IDE-td5015680.html

[Selenium IDE testing on maps(Open Layers)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13712252/selenium-ide-testing-on-mapsopen-layers)

http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.gis.openlayers.user/18125

Could you please explain it better? Or maybe show an example?

Thanks

PS: I am new to Selenium, so it might be a bit more difficult for me to understand it.

Comment: joaorodr84, I've the same problem, do you've any news about this stuff?

Comment: Hi @Cesare. I use Selenium WebDriver now. Please look at my full answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30437207/2280418

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is the best solution, but meanwhile I have started using [Selenium WebDriver](http://www.seleniumhq.org/projects/webdriver/), more specifically, the [Java version](http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/).

I have watched [this video](https://youtu.be/DO8KVe00kcU) about automated tests and it helped a lot for getting on the right track. The video shows some examples of the use of Selenium WebDriver (the C# version, but it is similar to the Java version).

I have installed the ChromeDriver but you can also do it fully in Firefox.

I use JUnit for the tests.

In Selenium IDE, you "record" the tests and then you replay them.

Here, in Selenium WebDriver, you fully write the tests, without recording anything.

For example, you write code for the following steps:

1) Open the web page of my OpenLayers (or other) app.

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://localhost/myOpenLayersApp/index.php");
```

2) Click on the button that opens page X

```
driver.findElement(By.id("Button-Go-to-page-X")).click();
```

3) Checks if you have indeed navigated to page X

```
boolean check = driver.findElement(By.id("Header-X"))
                    .getText()
                    .equals("This is page X.");
Assert.assertTrue(check);
```

This was a very simple example of how to use Selenium WebDriver. At least, this is how I use it.

If you have more questions, please feel free to ask. :)

***Note*: Watch the video if you are new to this. It is a very good lesson about automated testing.**